# "None of ['Horsepower'] are in the columns" error coming?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

CODE:-

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\DS\cars.csv',header=0)
df.columns
```

O/P:-

```
Index(['Car;MPG;Cylinders;Displacement;Horsepower;Weight;Acceleration;Model;Origin'], dtype='object')
```

CODE:-

```
df = df.set_index('Horsepower')
df.head

ERROR :- "None of ['Horsepower'] are in the columns"
```

I am using set_index for changing the index of DataFrame to 'Horsepower'. I am not able to identify where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your csv has semi-colon `;` as separator.

[`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) by default takes comma(`,`) as the separator, for all else, you need to explicitly pass the same:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Desktop\DS\cars.csv',header=0, sep=';')
```